# regular expression to match two different strings in PHP

Tags: php, expression

**How to find all the file names that contain `hello`, `English` and end with `.apk`.**

I currently have a regular expression that I use to find file names that contain `hello` and end with `.apk`.

```
preg_match('/.*hello.*\.apk$/i', $filename);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that with regular expressions but you'll eventually end up with ugly/complex/illegible expression. Instead use conjunction of simplier conditions joined togheter with logic operators:

```
if (strpos($filename, 'hello') !== 0 && strpos($filename, 'English') !== 0 && substr($filename, -4) === '.apk') {
    // filename matches
}
```

PHP's lack of standard string functions like `contains()` or `starts|endsWith()` makes above code a little bit ugly, but there's nothing that stopes you from creating a helper, utility class:

```
class StringHelper {
    private $subject;

    public function __construct($subject) {
        $this->subject = $subject;
    }

    public function contains($substring) {
        return strpos($this->subject, $substring) !== false;
    }

    public function endsWith($string) {
        return substr($this->subject, strlen($string) * -1) === $string;
    }
}
```

Then your `if` becomes even simpler:

```
$filename = new StringHelper($filename);

if ($filename->contains('hello') && $filename->contains('English') && $filename->endsWith('.apk')) {
    // matches
}
```

**Hint:** Instead of creating `StringHelper` object you could use a "classical" `StringUtilis` class with a bunch of static methods that accepts `$string` as their first argument.

**Hint:** `StringHelper::contains()` could accept an array of strings and check whether your string contains them all or at least one of them (depending on some sort of a flag given in second argument).

Comment: This gives an error for the use of $this when not in object context??

Answer (score 1):

This regex should do the trick if you need 'hello' OR 'English' in the file name :

`/.*(hello|English).*\.apk$/`

Comment: but it will check only for `hello` and `English`

Comment: @Glavic - I disagree, it sounds like he needs OR.

Comment: @nickb: he wrote, i cite "How to find all the file names that contain hello, English and end with .apk.". To me, this is AND.

Comment: @Glavic, yes, and he also wrote "regular expression to match **two different strings**". If it were AND, he's only matching one string. See how magnetik is right when he says that the OP's requirements are not clear?

Comment: @nickb, then there is a conflict, question title and body are crossing. We will see what OP really wants.

Comment: I need AND, this suggestion works, however it returns all the files that have any matches (OR). Would it be & instead of |?

Comment: When I said two different strings i meant that - must match "english" AND "Hello" AND end with .apx.

Answer (score 1):

If "English" must come after "hello":

```
if(preg_match('/.*hello.*English.*\.apk$/i', $filename));
```

If they can be in any order:

```
if(preg_match('/(hello.*English|English.*hello).*\.apk$/i', $filename));
```

Comment: Is there an version that states - must match hello and English (in any order) and ends with .apk?

Comment: `'/(hello.*English|English.*hello).*\.apk$/i'` should work, even if there's probably a more elegant way..

Comment: @ithcy, fix you answer for the future viewers.